# How to avoid having multiple values when assigning a variable multiple times

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-controller

I need to avoid getting duplicate values when I assign a value like this:

```
 hoursWorkedHelper : function(timeSheets){
        const hoursWorkedByContact = new Map();   
    if(timeSheets){                           
        timeSheets.forEach(timeSheet => {
            let copy = Object.assign({}, timeSheet);
            if(hoursWorkedByContact.has(copy.Contact__c)){
                copy.Name += ', ' + hoursWorkedByContact.get(copy.Contact__c).Name;
                copy.Project_Name__c += ', ' + hoursWorkedByContact.get(copy.Contact__c).Project_Name__c;
                console.log(copy.Project_Name__c);

            }
        })
    }
},
```

This is the line of code that gets duplicates when duplicate values are found:

```
    copy.Project_Name__c += ', ' + hoursWorkedByContact.get(copy.Contact__c).Project_Name__c;
```

For example, I want to avoid having this value on copy.Project_Name__c: "test, test, test 1", it should only be "test, test 1".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string manipulations use a Set to store unique values. Convert the final set into an array and use the `join()` method.

```
let projectNames = new Set();
timeSheets.forEach(timeSheet => {
    let copy = Object.assign({}, timeSheet);
    if(hoursWorkedByContact.has(copy.Contact__c)){
        projectNames.add(hoursWorkedByContact.get(copy.Contact__c).Project_Name__c);
    }
})

copy.Project_Name__c = [...projectNames].join(', ');
```